# How do you find height of mesh object?

Tags: c++, directx

I need a way to find height of object(.x). Is there simple way without using some complex math, E.g con or sin.

Comment: Trigonometric functions aren't "complex".

Comment: Well my options weren't limited to just function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there simple way without using some complex math

For each vertex, store the `min` and `max` value of the dimension that represents height (For example, `y`). If this is still "complex math", then you can use `D3DXComputeBoundingBox`.

Comment: ...which is pretty much what you do to compute a bounding box. No need to reinvent that wheel unless you really want to speed optimize it

Comment: Well D3DXComputeBoundingBox still need the max and min